# jQuery selectize select remove and add option on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js

I have used Selectize on a select box.

I am trying to remove an option when it is selected by clicking an external button. Likewise on clicking an external remove button, the option should go back to the list.

I have tried to experiment with the options provided by Selectize but I find myself unable to solve it given my scenario

Please have a look at my code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tytvmfqn/4/)

```
$(function(){
  $('#tax-statelist').selectize();

$('body').on('click', '#addSalesTaxState', function() {


var selectedState = $('#tax-statelist').val();

var selectedStateText = $('#tax-statelist option:selected').text();

if(selectedState != 'default') {
  var stateTax="";

stateTax += "<div class=\"commonclass-flex bottomspace1\">";
stateTax += "                         <input class=\"selectedStateText\" type=\"hidden\" value="+selectedStateText+" name=stateText[] \/>";
stateTax += "                         <input class=\"selectedStatePrefix\" type=\"hidden\" value="+selectedState+" name=stateprefix[] \/>";
stateTax += "                         <label class=\"rightspace1\">"+selectedState+"<\/label>";
stateTax += "                         <input class=\"inputstyle3\" name=statetaxvalue[] type=\"text\" value=\"\" required\/>";
stateTax += "                         <span>%<\/span>";
stateTax += "                         <div class=\"salestax-stateremove\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"removestatetax button-resets tooltip\" title=\"Remove State\"><\/button><\/div>";
stateTax += "                       <\/div>";

$('#createnew--salestax-per').append(stateTax)
$('#tax-statelist').val('default').trigger('change');
}
});

$('body').on('click', '.removestatetax', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});  

});
```

Comment: This link shows deleting an option with selectize: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873595/how-to-remove-an-item-from-selectize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873595/how-to-remove-an-item-from-selectize).

Answer (score 1):

This is all because of your selectize library that you're using, if you're going to insert, remove and stuff like this you should use it by selectize library api.
Anyway i commented your selectize library and fixed your code to work without it and states will be hidden when they are selected and will be shown again when they're removed from list.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhdmsm/k1a608tv/)

```js
$(function() {
  //$('#tax-statelist').selectize();

  $('body').on('click', '#addSalesTaxState', function() {


    var selectedState = $('#tax-statelist').val();

    var selectedStateText = $('#tax-statelist option:selected').text();
    $('#tax-statelist option:selected').hide();
    $('#tax-statelist').val('default');

    //$('#tax-statelist option:selected').hide();
    if (selectedState == null) {
      alert("pls select one the states first!");
      return;
    }

    if (selectedState != 'default') {
      var stateTax = "";

      stateTax += "<div class=\"commonclass-flex bottomspace1\">";
      stateTax += "                         <input class=\"selectedStateText\" type=\"hidden\" value=" + selectedStateText + " name=stateText[] \/>";
      stateTax += "                         <input class=\"selectedStatePrefix\" type=\"hidden\" value=" + selectedState + " name=stateprefix[] \/>";
      stateTax += "                         <label class=\"rightspace1\">" + selectedState + "<\/label>";
      stateTax += "                         <input class=\"inputstyle3\" name=statetaxvalue[] type=\"text\" value=\"\" required\/>";
      stateTax += "                         <span>%<\/span>";
      stateTax += "                         <div class=\"salestax-stateremove\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"removestatetax button-resets tooltip\" title=\"Remove State\"><\/button><\/div>";
      stateTax += "                       <\/div>";

      $('#createnew--salestax-per').append(stateTax)
        //$('#tax-statelist').val('default').trigger('change');
    }
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.removestatetax', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    var op_val = $(this).parent().parent().find('.rightspace1').html();
    $('#tax-statelist option[value=' + op_val + ']').show();
    $('#tax-statelist').val(op_val);
  });

});
```

```css
.salestax-stateremove button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(http://cortechindia.com/wip/lag/images/icon_salestax-remove.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="tax-statelist" placeholder="Choose State...">
    <option disabled value="default">Choose State...</option>
    <option value="AA">APO/FPO AA</option>
    <option value="AP">APO/FPO AP</option>
    <option value="AE">APO/FPO AE</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="createnew--addnewstate" class="leftspace1">
  <button id="addSalesTaxState" class="button-resets actions-button__text actions-button-addstate">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="createnew--salestax-per">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am already able to do that without selectize. All other forms in my page are using selectize and hence I am trying to make this work with it.